# camerakit.CameraView library crashing a lot

Tags: android, camera

I am using a camera view library for capturing images directly. But it crashes a lot whenever the activity containing it is opened. First of all my code is:

```
mCameraView.setCameraListener(new CameraListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] jpeg) {
            super.onPictureTaken(jpeg);
            // Create a bitmap

        }
    });

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mCameraView.start();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    mCameraView.stop();
    super.onPause();
}

    captureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mCameraView.captureImage();
        }
    });
```

Now the crash occurs mostly not after i have clicked any button but the moment the activity containing this is opened.
Errors are like:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: setPreviewTexture failed
       at com.flurgle.camerakit.Camera1.setupPreview(Camera1.java:333)
       at com.flurgle.camerakit.Camera1.start(Camera1.java:86)
       at com.flurgle.camerakit.CameraView$3.run(CameraView.java:216)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by java.io.IOException: setPreviewTexture failed
       at android.hardware.Camera.setPreviewTexture(Camera.java)
       at com.flurgle.camerakit.Camera1.setupPreview(Camera1.java:330)
       at com.flurgle.camerakit.Camera1.start(Camera1.java:86)
       at com.flurgle.camerakit.CameraView$3.run(CameraView.java:216)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

or it is:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed
       at android.hardware.Camera.native_setParameters(Camera.java)
       at android.hardware.Camera.setParameters(Camera.java:1878)
       at com.flurgle.camerakit.Camera1.setFlash(Camera1.java:139)
       at com.flurgle.camerakit.Camera1.adjustCameraParameters(Camera1.java:376)
       at com.flurgle.camerakit.Camera1.openCamera(Camera1.java:317)
       at com.flurgle.camerakit.Camera1.start(Camera1.java:85)
       at com.flurgle.camerakit.CameraView$3.run(CameraView.java:216)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

i searched on internet but doesn't look like people have found issues with it or maybe people don't use it. Anyways it's annoying me a lot , help would be really appreciated.
btw library is [this one](https://github.com/gogopop/CameraKit-Android)

Comment: it's probably a bad library. I also used it for video capturing and it does crash. Don't use it!

Comment: Which library would you suggest? I am also using the same library. I asked because its a few month old question. so may be you guys end-up with some solution.

Comment: i didn't use any library at the end i just used the actual code without any library